# Login com PDO não verifica número de resultados de select

Tags: php, pdo

Estou começando um novo sistema só que em vez de procedural estou usando O.O. e PDO, comecei a fazer o login, porém mesmo a select retornando o valor, o PHP mostra que usuário ou senha está errado...

Método de login:

```
static function login($usuario, $senha) {
    try {

        $con = ConnectionFactory::getConnection();

        $con->beginTransaction();

        $senha = base64_encode($senha);

        $stmt = $con->prepare("select usuario from tbl_login where usuario = '?' and senha = '?'");

        $stmt->bindParam(1, $usuario);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $senha);

        $stmt->execute();
        $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // tentei colocar tmb $stmt->rowCount() == 1
        if(count($users) == 1){
            echo '<script> alert("Bem vindo ao sistema!");
                           window.location("menu.php"); </script>';
        } else {
            echo '<script> alert("Usuário ou senha incorretos!");
                           window.location("login.php"); </script>';
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` já retorna true ou false caso haja algum registro, se não me engano

Comment: Dá um `var_dump($user)` para ver o que retorna

Comment: O problema pode estar na query, bom, eu não gosto muito de usar question mark's (?) Por que não tenta usando os dois pontos (:) e não é necessário as aspas, "select usuario from tbl_login where usuario = :usuario and senha = :senha" e nos binds faça assim exemplo: $stmt->bindParam('usuario', $usuario); a proósito não salve as senhas em base_64 pois pode ser revertida, inves disso use outro tipo como MD5 ou Sha1

Comment: Não vai aspas simplas nas interrogações

Comment: Obrigado Woton, funcionou. Anderson, eu troquei por :usuario..., a respeito da senha, se eu usar o MD5, como eu faria para verificar a senha que o cara digitou com a senha do banco?

Comment: Já descobri como funciona ao usar o MD5.. (só gerar o MD5 da senha digitada e ver se bate com a do banco..)

Answer (score 0):

É necessário verificar o retorno.

```
//Pode usar o var_dump ou print_r
var_dump($users)
print_r($users)
```

Recomendo o var_dump